# Displayed text in WPF combo box with MenuItems and radio buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combo box with radio buttons and checkable menu items. When I select a value some text of the radio buttons (Include / Exclude / Ignore) is displayed. This seems to be randomly  and does not happen always, but only sometimes.

What I want is that a) no text at all is displayed or b) I can have a binding for a string property, which will contain some summary of what is selected. Unlike in normal combo boxes, the displayed text here is meaningless, since I do select some arbitrary combination of options (not a single value out of a list)

I have tried to bind Text / SelecteValue against a property, but this does not work.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" SelectedValue="{Binding Settings.NameFilterTrx.Summary, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  Mode=OneWay}">
  <MenuItem Header="Names with runway" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Settings.NameFilterTrx.NamesWithRunway, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  <MenuItem Header="Names with number" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Settings.NameFilterTrxNamesWithNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  <MenuItem Header="Filtered elements as comments" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Settings.NameFilterTrx.FilteredAsComments, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  <RadioButton GroupName="Group" Content="Exclude" IsChecked="{Binding Settings.NameFilterTrx.ModeExclude, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,2,0,3"/>
  <RadioButton GroupName="Group" Content="Include" IsChecked="{Binding Settings.NameFilterTrx.ModeInclude, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,2,0,3"/>
  <RadioButton GroupName="Group" Content="Ignore"  IsChecked="{Binding Settings.NameFilterTrx.ModeIgnore, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,2,0,3"/>
</ComboBox>
```

As you can see the text does not correspond with the selected value. Also only text of the radio buttons is randomly displayed, never something of the menu items.

[image: Screenshot]

PS: The binding for `SelectedValue` is one of my trails to get a defined value. If have tried `Text` as well as no binding.

Comment: Why don't you use an Expander to fulfill your goal? It looks like a combobox and you will not be bothered by the selected value of the combobox.

Comment: Maybe a good idea, let me try.

Comment: One more thing, when the Expander is expanded, it may change the size of your parent container. So what I usually do is to put it in a Grid and specify it to span several rows and columns. Then I will set the z-index of the Expander to a large value. So the expanded Expander will overlay the other controls and not change the size of the parent panel.

Comment: This is cool, I just have realized this issue and the answer is already there ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use an expander to fullfill your goal. The problem with this solution is that when the Expander is expanded, it may change the size of your parent container. So what I usually do is to put it in a Grid and specify it to span several rows and columns. Then I will set the z-index of the Expander to a large value. So the expanded Expander will overlay the other controls and not change the size of the parent panel. :)

Comment: I have used your approach, and also tried / used a menu for the same situation as well (based on your idea). Both concepts have pros and cons, but are better than the combo box in this particular case.